# keytool -list -keystore FILE_KEYSTORE.pfx returns Invalid keystore format

Tags: certificate, keystore, explorer

I have a digital certificate that is valid on IE, but when I try to list using the keytool is returning

**Command:** keytool -list -keystore 9612267.pfx

**Returns**
keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format

When I try to open using the KeyStoreExplorer tool shows an error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
java.util.Vector.elementAt(Unknown Source)
org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Set.getObjectAt(Unknown Source)
org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.keystore.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStoreSpi.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've added the -storetype pkcs12 then the command worked:
 keytool -list -keystore 9612267.pfx -storetype pkcs12